# List saved files in iOS documents directory in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, afnetworking

I have set up the following code to save a file to the documents directory:

```
NSLog(@"Saving File...");

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.reddexuk.com/logo.png"]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"logo.png"];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```

However, I wish to add each file to a UITableView when it is successfully saved. When the file in the UITableView is tapped, I'd like a UIWebView to navigate to that file (all offline).

Also - how can I just get the filename and ending such as "logo.png" instead of http://www.reddexuk.com/logo.png?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Here is the method I use to get the content of a directory.

```
-(NSArray *)listFileAtPath:(NSString *)path
{
    //-----> LIST ALL FILES <-----//
    NSLog(@"LISTING ALL FILES FOUND");

    int count;

    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];
    for (count = 0; count < (int)[directoryContent count]; count++)
    {
        NSLog(@"File %d: %@", (count + 1), [directoryContent objectAtIndex:count]);
    }
    return directoryContent;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how do I put this data into a UITableView and then open the file in UIWebView?

Comment: Here is a good [UITableView](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/) tutorial and here is the link to the [xcode project](https://github.com/cwalcott/UITableView-Tutorial) for this tutorial. Here is a good tutorial on [UIWebView](http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/08/uiwebview-tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks for that. I know how to create a UITableView etc but not sure how to get the files actually into the UITableView itself. The site you sent doesn't really mention that either :(

Comment: Just assuming that your array to fill your table view is called "tableArray" and the code is in the same class file as your table.
`NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
tableArray = [self listFileAtPath:documentsDirectory];`

Comment: thanks! So where would I post this code? Would you be able to edit your answer to show how I can put the data into the UITableView (for example, what would go in - **(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {** )

Comment: I put that code in my viewDidLoad method and an error came up - http://file.reddexuk.com/2W0k3J031J400j3T0g0P

Answer (score 21):

```
-(NSArray *)findFiles:(NSString *)extension{

NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSFileManager *fManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *item;
NSArray *contents = [fManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] error:nil];

// >>> this section here adds all files with the chosen extension to an array
for (item in contents){
    if ([[item pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) {
        [matches addObject:item];
    }
}
return matches; }
```

The example above is pretty self-explanatory. I hope it answers you second question.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I was really asking for. I don't want to find multiple file names, I just want to cut out the http://www.domain.com/ so i'm left with the "file.suffix" bit at the end. Surely there's a quicker way to do that?

Comment: @Mike Martin your answer gave me an idea to solve a problem I am facing right now. Thank you.
P.S. Just one more thing, what if I need to add in "matches" files (objects) that might have an extension from the following set: @"txt", @"pdf", @"doc", @"rtf", @"png", @"jpeg"?

Answer (score 11):

To get the contents of a directory

```
- (NSArray *)ls {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: documentsDirectory];

    NSLog(@"%@", documentsDirectory);
    return directoryContent;
}
```

To get the last path component,

```
[[path pathComponents] lastObject]
```

Comment: thanks, but how do I put this data into a UITableView and then open the file in UIWebView? Also, "[[path pathComponents] lastObject]" wouldn't get the full filename just the file type (e.g. ".gif" not "test.gif") so what can I do to get "test.gif"?

Comment: I suggest reading up on UITableViews. A full length tutorial is not really gonna happen on Stack Overflow

Comment: but @coneybeare - you did not mention anything in reply to the comment about filetypes. I am also keen to do this. Can you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: pathcomponents splits on @"/" giving you what you want.

Comment: `directoryContentsAtPath` is deprecated, use `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath`

Comment: This answer was written in 2010

Answer (score 8):

Thanks Alex,

Here is Swift version

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentDirectory = paths[0]
if let allItems = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentDirectory) {
    print(allItems)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but it's a good one and things have changed in iOS post Sandboxing.

The path to all the readable/writeable folders within the app *will* now have a hash in it and Apple reserves the right to change that path at any time.  It *will* change on every app launch for sure.

You'll need to get the path to the folder you want and you can't hardcode it like we used to be able to do in the past.

You ask for the documents directory and in the return array, it's at position 0.  Then from there, you use that value to supply to the NSFileManager to get the directory contents.

The code below works under iOS 7 and 8 to return an array of the contents within the documents directory.  You may want to sort it according to your own preferences.

```
+ (NSArray *)dumpDocumentsDirectoryContents {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", directoryContents);
    return directoryContents;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For a more reasonable filename:

`NSString *filename = [[url lastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathExtension:[url pathExtension]];`

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 5

Function that returns array of URLs of all files in Documents directory that are MP4/M4V videos. If you want all files, just remove the `filter`.

It checks only files in the top directory. If you want to list also files in the subdirectories, remove the `.skipsSubdirectoryDescendants` option.

```
func listVideos() -> [URL] {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

    let files = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(
        at: documentDirectory,
        includingPropertiesForKeys: nil,
        options: [.skipsSubdirectoryDescendants, .skipsHiddenFiles]
    ).filter {
        ["mp4", "m4v"].contains($0.pathExtension.lowercased())
    }

    return files ?? []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:dir_path];

NSString *filename;

while ((filename = [dirEnum nextObject]))
{
    // Do something amazing
}
```

for enumerating through ALL files in directory

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.x**

```
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
if let allItems = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentDirectory) {
  print(allItems)
}
```

Comment: how to get file list from "Documents/Inbox"? and select any one.