# DocumentsDirectory in UITableView Array for Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0

Tags: uitableview, directory, swift2, document, xcode7.1

I have a project I'm working on that creates and saves PDF files locally to the `DocumentDirectoy`.  I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721418/ios-swift-getting-list-of-files-in-documents-folder) on how to view the `DocumentDirectory` and filtering it for it for `PDF` files.  I want to have the `DocumentDirectory` files be viewable in a `UITableView`. I know I have to have an `array` for that.  I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376511/list-saved-files-in-ios-documents-directory-in-a-uitableview) on doing this, but can't figure out how to get the `DocumentDirectory` into an array in Swift 2.0 to display in my `UITableView`.  My PDF files are saving and are viewable in my `UIWebView`.

My code for viewing my `DocumentDirectory` PDFs is:

```
    func itemsInDirectory() {

    // We need just to get the documents folder url
    let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!

    // now lets get the directory contents (including folders)
    do {
        let directoryContents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
        print("Items: \(directoryContents)")

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // if you want to filter the directory contents you can do like this:
    do {
        let directoryUrls = try  NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
        print(directoryUrls)
        let PDFFiles = directoryUrls.filter(){ $0.pathExtension == "pdf" }.map{ $0.lastPathComponent }
        print("PDF FILES:\n" + PDFFiles.description)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

It prints them when I run it.  Can someone please help me with converting the `DocumentDirectory` to an array to view in my `UITableView`? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In my main menu `View Controller` in the `ViewDidLoad()` section I added:

```
    // Get the documents folder url
    let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!

    // Filter for PDF only
    do {
        let directoryUrls = try  NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
        let PDFFiles = directoryUrls.filter(){ $0.pathExtension == "pdf" }.map{ $0.lastPathComponent }

        // Set TableView array for saved files to DocumentDirectory PDFs
        savedPDFFiles = PDFFiles
        print(savedPDFFiles)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

In my other `Table View Controller`, I set `savedPDFFiles` as a `Global Variable`.  When loading my `Table View Controller`, the table shows my `DocumentDirectory`files by name.