# Display and open saved files on TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I made an pdf creator app. After creating pdf file I want to display the created files on a `tableview`. I created Tableview Controller and `DocumentDirectoryTableTableViewController`. I don't know how to do it after all of that.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007620/documentsdirectory-in-uitableview-array-for-xcode-7-and-swift-2-0) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721418/getting-list-of-files-in-documents-folder) questions but I couldn't implement it into my code.

Also better to add my code for saving file:

```
        // 5. Save PDF file
    let path = "/MyApp/PdfFiles/MyPDF.pdf"
    pdfData.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)
    print("open \(path)") // command to open the generated file
```

**UPDATE:**
I can also get the App Directory and use it by this function:

```
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

and

```
let path = "\(getDocumentsDirectory())MyApp.pdf"
```

Comment: My problem is that I can't match these codes. I mean on I save here: `/MyApp/PdfFiles/MyPDF.pdf` but I have no idea how to implement this directory to the code. What's wrong with `print("open \(path)")`? I'm new developer please bear with me. @KrishnaCA

Comment: I just checked your updated code. At exactly what point are you stuck at? Also, you initial path "/MyApp/PdfFiles/MyPDF.pdf" is not correct. Because iOS file paths start differently. The way you are doing it in your updated code is correct

Comment: @KrishnaCA The problem is: I don't see any file on the tableview when I run the app. Even with the updated code I can't see any file.

Comment: Are you reading the file correctly?

Comment: @KrishnaCA Where should I implement the code that I have linked to DocumentDirectoryTableTableViewController.Swift exactly? I guess I have problem there.

Comment: I believe your reading part goes like this. 1) Display the name of files on UITableView 2) click on any file, display the entire pdf. Is this right?

Comment: @KrishnaCA yes I want to do it exactly

Comment: Do you also want to write some `NSData` to pdf file?

Comment: Hi, I wrote an answer. Let me know if it helps or not. If it doesn't, please let me know where you have doubt

Answer (score 1):

If you have `NSData` for the pdf file you're trying to store and if you want user to access it, you can write it using this:

```
func writePDF(data: NSData, to Name:String) -> Bool {

    let pdfData:NSData = data

    let pdfPaths:[String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    var pdfPath = pdfPaths[0]
    pdfPath.append("_\(Name).pdf")
    let result:Bool = pdfData.write(toFile: pdfPath, atomically: true)

    return result
}
```

If you want to read pdf file programatically in your app given that you store it in the above path. It can be done using this:

```
func readPDF(Name: String) {

    let pdfPaths:[String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    var pdfPath = pdfPaths[0]
    pdfPath.append("_\(Name).pdf")
    if let pdfData:NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pdfPath) { // verifying pdf exists in this path
        let documentController: UIDocumentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: pdfPath))
        documentController.delegate = self
        documentController.presentPreview(animated: true)
    }
}

// the below delegate function for `UIDocumentInteractionController` is necessary for it to present in the current `UIViewController`
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    return self
}
```

Comment: I'm trying the function `readPDF`. What should I write for the `Name: String` when I call the function?

Comment: Did you save your pdf i.e write it somewhere?