# Import directory with UIDocumentPickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, icloud, uidocumentpickervc

I try to implement UIDocumentPickerController in my application. 
Is there any way to import whole directory with contained files or this solution allow only for import single files?

What is your recommendation?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

u can get list of files and folders in [List saved files in iOS documents directory in a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376511/list-saved-files-in-ios-documents-directory-in-a-uitableview)

u can get get all files and folders from specific directory.
then copy all contents from other app directory to ur app directory.